# Double scrollbar because off mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mmenu

I need to create menu for mobile. I chose mmenu jquery.
So, menu works well, but after inserting this code:

```
var config = {
        "#slide-menu": {
            pageSelector: "mm-page",
            offCanvas: {
                position  : "left",
                zposition : "front"
            }
        }
    };

    for (var selector in config) {
        if (jQuery(selector)[0]) {
            jQuery(selector).mmenu(config[selector]);

            jQuery('#close-slide-menu').on('click', function() {

                jQuery(selector).trigger('close.mm');
            });

            jQuery(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
                    jQuery(selector).trigger('close.mm');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

, there was a problem with double scroll.
I cannot slide from top to bottom with 1 touch. On the center my sliding stop.

[image]

p.s. sorry for my English

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mind sharing your html so that i may better understand what is happening. Might be that your **content is overflowing** your container which causes the **double scrollbar**. Would usually be something like **margin** or **padding** causing the issue.